# Running a file with command as service in the background

Tags: command-line, server

Basically what I have to do is run the following command,

```
./home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/build/bin/monero-stratum /home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/config.json
```

the only disadvantage that this brings with it is that I can't do anything else. So I would like to make it run in the background so that I can do other things on my linux server in the mean time.

For the record I am running Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server.

I have ran true different solutions but quiet honestly most off them are to far out of my knowledge and understanding off linux.

Comment: What have you tried ? `/home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/build/bin/monero-stratum /home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/config.json &` or better use screen to you can reattach if needed. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen

Comment: tried not really much since I am to affraid to mess things up and having to redo everything from scratch.  I have basically been going trough forums looking to answers on similar questions but tbh I don't have much experience in scripts etc.

Comment: Give it some time, "knowledge and understanding" will improve.

Comment: I think other alternative is to append this line-command to `~/.profile`, so this command will be run at session startup. My question is: How many times will `~/.profile` be executed in a user session? Because I know `~/.bashrc` will be executed whenever we open a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok that your terminal needs to be open, the common way would be to append `&` to your command (as previously mentioned). But I would not recommend that as you won't be able to use the terminal any more (your command will still promt its output).
It's better to forward the output to a file or - if you don't need the output - to "nowhere" by appending `> /dev/null > 2>&1 &`.
The `> /dev/null` redirects all output to "nowhere", including errors (`2>&1`) and the last `&` executes the command in the background..
Try:

```
./home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/build/bin/monero-stratum /home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/config.json > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I think, there is no way to do it any simpler, but using a daemon would be better. Depends on your requirements...

Comment: Thanks this did it for me, just added "> /dev/null 2>&1 &" after my command and id did what I wanted it to do.  gotta love Linux and it's community.

Answer (score 0):

As bodhi.zazin suggested:

```
./home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/build/bin/monero-stratum /home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/config.json &
```

Another option might be to run it as a [daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/daemon.1.html) process. If using a graphical terminal, this would allow you to close the terminal without aborting the process. You can read a general description of daemon processes [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to redirecting the output, you can protect the process from your logout by using "nohup" as in

```
nuhup ./home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/build/bin/monero-stratum /home/pooldaemon/monero-stratum/config.json &
```

The nohup command traps the hangup signal that processes can receive when a parent process terminates.